# How to simplify this HypergeometricPFQ function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

1. I want to simplify this expression

   `HypergeometricPFQ[{-12 + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-11 + x/2, x}, 1]`

I tried to use `FunctionExpand` at first but it just returns the unchanged input.

2. But I found Mathematica can simplify

   `HypergeometricPFQ[{-a + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-(a-1) + x/2, x}, 1]`

when $1\leq a\leq11$, I just use this command line

`HypergeometricPFQ[{-a + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-(a-1) + x/2, x}, 1]//FunctionExpand`

to simplify it.

For example, If I use

`HypergeometricPFQ[{-2 + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-(2-1) + x/2, x}, 1]//FunctionExpand`

I can get
$\frac{2^{-1+x}\Gamma(1/2+x/2)}{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma[2+x/2]}+\frac{2 \Gamma(1+x)}{(-2+x)^2 \Gamma(-2+x/2)\Gamma(2+x/2)}$

3. I tried to simplify

   `HypergeometricPFQ[{-12 + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-11 + x/2, x}, 1]`

   using the definition of the Generalized Hypergeometric Function

$_3F_2({a_1,a_2,a_3};{b_1,b_2};z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (a_1)_k(a_2)_k(a_3)_k/(b_1)_k(b_2)_k z^k/k!$

to expand the the expression at first,
then I simplify these items using `Simplify` and `FunctionExpand`. Finally I tried to sum these terms again, but I sill could not get a simplified result.

4. My question is why Mathematica just returns me the unchanged input when $a=12$ but returns the simplified expression when $ 1\leq a\leq 11$?

Comment: If you clarify the following points, you'll more likely get some hints or help.1. You mean that expression, not equation, don't you?  2. How did you simplify that expression? 3. What did you try?

Comment: I think you should make it explicit that when using `a=12` just the input is returned unchanged:  `HypergeometricPFQ[{-12 + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-11 + x/2, x}, 1]` is returned as opposed to just saying "it fails to simplify".

Comment: Are you aware of [Saalschütz's identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaalschuetzsTheorem.html)?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties  How do you know all this stuff?!  That seems to give a compact result but only for non-positive even integers for $x$.  If one uses `HypergeometricPFQ[{-a + x/2, x/2, x/2}, {-(a-1) + x/2, x}, 1]//FunctionExpand//FullSimplify` for values of $a$ from 1 to 11, then a "nice" pattern arises.  I can't believe that pattern no longer exists starting at $a=12$.  *Mathematica* must have some hardwired stopping threshold set at 12.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I found another identity, `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b, a - n}, {d, a - n + 1}, 1] == (((a - n) Pochhammer[b - a, n] (n - 1)!)/((a - b) Pochhammer[1 - a, n] Pochhammer[d - a, n])) ((Gamma[d] Gamma[d - a - b + 1])/ (Gamma[d - a] Gamma[d - b])) Sum[(Pochhammer[1 - a, k] Pochhammer[d - a, k])/ (k! Pochhammer[b - a + 1, k]), {k, 0, n - 1}]` which is useful in my case.